# Parse css and generate file with PHP-CSS-PARSE

Tags: php, css, parsing

I'm trying to parse a CSS file with the Raphael Schweikert's lib [Sabberworm\PHP-CSS-PARSE](https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser)

But I'm blocked with object manipulations. What I'm trying to do is to convert this css file:

```
.header {
  background: #000;
}

.footer, .wrapper {
  background: #ebebeb;
}
```

In a PHP/JSON like format:

```
 '.header'  => "background: #000;",
 '.footer'  => "background: #ebebeb;",
 '.wrapper' => "background: #ebebeb;"
```

What i did:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$oCssParser = new Sabberworm\CSS\Parser(file_get_contents('style.css'));
$oCssDocument = $oCssParser->parse();
$selectors=$oCssDocument->getAllRuleSets();
...
```

but how to loop after ? The structure of the object is not easy for a neewbe like me...

Answer (score 0):

(This should be a comment, but with the code this is better readable).

I'm not familiar with PHP-CSS-PARSE, but I have one observation: I would assume

```
.footer .wrapper {
  background: #ebebeb;
}
```

would become `'.footer .wrapper'  => "background: #ebebeb;"`.

If you want

```
'.footer'  => "background: #ebebeb;",
'.wrapper' => "background: #ebebeb;"
```

then the CSS would have to be

```
.footer, .wrapper {
  background: #ebebeb;
}
```

(notice the comma) or have to have separate rules.

Comment: oups you are right. I missed the coma. My source is effectively
  .footer, .wrapper {
     background: #ebebeb;
   }

Answer (score 0):

I was lazy yesterday...

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$oCssParser = new Sabberworm\CSS\Parser(file_get_contents('style.css'));
$oCssDocument = $oCssParser->parse();

foreach ($oCssDocument->getAllRuleSets() as $oRuleSet) {

    $sSelector = $oRuleSet->getSelectors();
    foreach ($sSelector as $currentSelector) {
            $sSelector = $currentSelector->getSelector();
            echo "\r\n\"$sSelector\" = \"";
            foreach( $oRuleSet->getRules() as $sRules) {
                echo "$sRules ";
            }
            echo "\"";
    }
}
```

wich renders

```
".header" = "background: #000; "
".footer" = "background: #ebebeb; "
".wrapper" = "background: #ebebeb; "
```